# jQuery and C# dynamic dropdown

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I am using a couple of C# Lists in a class to create two dropdowns in a form - one for department and one for subdepartment.

When a user clicks on the department I would like the values in the subdepartment to automatically change with jQuery.

So far I have the following for my html form:

```
<tr>
        <td><strong>Department *</strong></td>
        <td>
            <select name="ctl00$mainContent$uxDDListDepartment" id="ctl00_mainContent_uxDDListDepartment">
            <% if (DepartmentsList != null && DepartmentsList.Count > 0)
               { %>
                <% foreach (var i in DepartmentsList)
                   { %>
                    <option value="<%= i.DepartmentId %>"
                    <% if (Job != null && Job.Count > 0) { %>
                        <% foreach (var j in Job) { %>
                            <% if(j.Department == i.Description) { %>selected="selected"<% } %>    
                        <% } %>               
                   <% } %>                        
                    ><%= i.Description %></option>
                <% } %>               
           <% } %>
           </select>
           <span id="ctl00_mainContent_uxValDDListDepartment" class="error" style="color:#891F11;display:none;">Please enter a department</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Sub Department</strong></td>
        <td>
            <select name="ctl00$mainContent$uxDDListSubDepartment" id="ctl00_mainContent_uxDDListSubDepartment">               
             <% if (SubDepartmentsList != null && SubDepartmentsList.Count > 0) { %>
                <% foreach (var i in SubDepartmentsList)
                   { %>
                         <% if (Job != null && Job.Count > 0) { %>
                            <% foreach (var j in Job) { %>
                                <% if(j.DepartmentId == i.DepartmentId) { %>                           
                                        <option value="<%= i.SubDepartmentId %>"><%= i.Description %></option>
                                 <% } %>
                              <% } %>               
                        <% } %> 
                <% } %>               
           <% } %>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And for the jQuery (I haven't got very far!) all I have is:

```
// Departments
$("#ctl00_mainContent_uxDDListDepartment").change(function () {

    var departmentId = $('#ctl00_mainContent_uxDDListDepartment').val();

    alert(departmentId);


});
```

To pull out the departmentId.

How can I dynamically get the form to change the subdepartment values when a user changes the department value?

Thanks

Comment: if this is asp.net c# then you can use [Update Panels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454(v=vs.100).aspx) otherwise if you want to manually change this you need to have a look at making an [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

if you intend to implement the filtering logic at client side, then you can use $(selector).each to get the options of the dropdown and perform your logic.

```
var options = [];
$("#ctl00_mainContent_uxDDListSubDepartment option").each(function()
{
    options.push($(this).val());
});
```